# Python3: pexpect issue about expect list

Tags: python-3.x, expect, pexpect

Here comes the template, in the while loop , variable "index" is a list, So , I can't understand the code "if index == 0" mean, does index[0] = "suc", index[1]="fail" ? please make it as more clear as possible。

```
 import pexpect
 while True:
    index = child.expect(["suc","fail",pexpect.TIMEOUT])
    if index == 0:
        break
    elif index == 1:
        return False
    elif index == 2:
        pass        #continue to wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expect() method returns the index of the pattern that is matched. index is not a list.

According to the [manual](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pexpect/latest/pexpect.pdf):

> `expect(pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False)`
>
> This seeks through the stream until a pattern is matched. **The *pattern* is overloaded** and may take several
>   types. The pattern can be a StringType, EOF, a compiled re, or a list of any of those types. Strings will be
>   compiled to re types. **This returns the index into the pattern list. If the pattern was not a list this returns
>   index 0 on a successful match.** This may raise exceptions for EOF or TIMEOUT. To avoid the EOF or
>   TIMEOUT exceptions add EOF or TIMEOUT to the pattern list. That will cause expect to match an EOF
>   or TIMEOUT condition instead of raising an exception.
>
> If you pass a list of patterns and more than one matches, the first match in the stream is chosen. If more
>   than one pattern matches at that point, the leftmost in the pattern list is chosen.